# How could I limit a query in postgresql to 50% of the data when calling for the table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to bring 50% of the data contained in the data table

that is, if I have 10 lines, only bring 5 but without using limit 5, since it has to be constant depending on the number of lines

Select * from data limit 50% this generates an error

how could it be done?

Answer (score 4):

If you want a random sample and an approximate 50% is sufficient, you can use `tablesample`:

```
select t.*
from t tablesample bernoulli (50);
```

Otherwise, you can define the sample yourself to get exactly (or off-by-1) 50%:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, ntile(2) over (order by random()) as tile
      from t
     ) t
where tile = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a unique column then you can use percent_rank() window function to get your desired data.

Here we have create a table with ID and code column then inserted four rows. Below query is returning 2 rows. If there were five rows it would have returned 3 rows.

Schema and insert statements:

```
create table temp (id int, code varchar(50));
     insert into temp values(1,'a');
     insert into temp values(2,'b');
     insert into temp values(3,'c');
     insert into temp values(4,'d');
```

Query:

```
     SELECT
         ID,
         Code
     FROM (
         SELECT
             ID,
             COde,
             percent_rank() over (order by id desc) as pct_rank
         FROM temp
         ) t
     WHERE pct_rank <= 0.50;
```

Output:

| id | code |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | d |
| 3 | c |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=67fe98078a814400a15cf1364165aa57)*

You can also use `cume_dist()` same way.